# Proper terminology for HTTP

Tags: http, terminology

I hate to ask a question with such little merit, considering it's documented, but I was wondering if someone could give me a hand in understanding the terminology behind HTTP. I know I could just read the documents, but sometimes it feels a little thick and it's hard to understand what they're trying to say.

Here's what I'm getting so far:

---

The entire transaction consists of messages, which are either Requests or Responses.

Start line?

```
[method/verb] [url?] [version?]
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

A message header

```
[name]: [value (which is LWS and content)]
Host: google.com\r\n
\r\n
```

--

```
[version?] [status code] [description?]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-type: text/plain\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
\r\n
```

Message body?

```
d\r\n
Hello, world!\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

(and, the entity body would just be "Hello world!" / the version of the message body sans encoding? Or, would it only be a 'message body' as opposed to an entity body if it were encoded?)

---

I appreciate any notes/insight/corrections you may have. I'm currently attempting to write an HTTP engine, so I feel it's worth the investment to ensure proper terminology is used. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this terminology can be found in the RFC documents from IETF. Specifically, you're interested in [RFC 2616](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2616/?include_text=1). If you're writing your own HTTP engine, reading at least RFC 2616 is a must, along with RFCs [1738](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1738/?include_text=1), [1808](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1808/?include_text=1) and [2396](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2396/?include_text=1).

Here are some relevant excerpts that answer your questions:

```
Request       = Request-Line              ; Section 5.1
                *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                 | request-header         ; Section 5.3
                 | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                CRLF
                [ message-body ]          ; Section 4.3

Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                 | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                 | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                CRLF
                [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2

Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```